# Polar to rectangular $r = 7$

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

I don't follow this at all. I have $r = 7$ and the formula states $x = r \cos\theta$ $y = r\sin\theta$ but my book gives $x^2 + y^2 = 49$ this is impossible. It doens't follow the formula at all. Since theta isn't present it is zero. This gives. $x = 7$ and $y = 0$ why does the formula fail?

Comment: Since $\theta$ is not present, it can be *any* value.

Comment: but the book said $x=r \cos \theta$ and $y=r \sin \theta$ so $x^2+y^2=r^2 \cos^2 \theta +r^2 \sin^2 \theta=r^2(cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta)=r^2(1)$ using $\cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta=1$ , does that help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The formula is fine. We have $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$ by Pythagoras theorem. Or you can use the given formulas to get
$$
x^2 + y^2 = (r\cos(\theta))^2 + (r\sin(\theta))^2 = r^2(\cos^2(\theta) + \sin^2(\theta)) = r^2
$$since $\cos^2(\theta) + \sin^2(\theta) = 1$. For $r = 7$, we have $x^2 + y^2 = r^2 = 7^2 = 49$.

As you can see from the above, $\theta$ disappears because of the trigonometric identity (not because it's zero) which basically is a consequence of Pythagoras theorem.

[image]

Comment: I don't follow why we have x^2 + y^2 = r^2

Comment: How would I apply it to $$r = 2sin/theta$$?

Comment: Can you see the right angle triangle formed by the radial line, the vertical line on the right and the horizontal axis? Using Pythagoras theorem, we have $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$. Read about it on wikipedia if you don't know what it is. The other way is using trigonometry. After squaring the two terms, $r^2$ factors out and what's left is equal to one by a trigonometric identity as I wrote in my answer (which comes from Pythagorous so The first method is more fundamental).

Comment: $r = 2sin/theta$ doesn't even make sense. Did you make a typo?

Comment: But if x is defined by r and r is defined by theta how do I find x?

Comment: @PaulthePirate They are not definitions. The formulas show the relation between the two coordinate system. They allow you to change the coordinates from polar or cartesian to the other. Clearly the point on the graph must be given in terms of one of the coordinate system (either $r$ and $\theta$ or $x$ and $y$ must be given). For example,if $x=1$ and $y=1$, then $r=\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}=\sqrt{2}$ and $\theta=\tan^{-1}(1)=\pi/4$ ($45^\circ$). We can go backwards in the same example using the formulas: $x=r\sin(\theta)=\sqrt{2}\sin(\pi/4)=\sqrt{2}/\sqrt{2}=1$ and $y=r\cos(\theta)=\sqrt{2}/\sqrt{2}=1$

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10124/discussion-between-pratyush-sarkar-and-paul-the-pirate)

Comment: @PaulthePirate I opened chat if you want to continue the discussion.

Comment: I can't chat actually, but I think I understand what oyu are saying I just cna't apply it. What if I have $r=2sin\theta$?

Comment: When you have $r = 2\sin(\theta)$, then you have different values of $r$ for different values of $\theta$. So you get a collection of points (not just one). If you graph it, you will get a line (its basically a polar equation of a line). When you use the formulas to change into cartesian coordinate, you are basically changing into cartesian coordinates for all the points and the results is a cartesian equation for the same line. You get $y = r\sin(\theta) = 2\sin(\theta) \cdot \sin(\theta) = 2\sin^2(\theta)$

Comment: @PaulthePirate Continuing the comment: we also have $x = r\cos(\theta) = 2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta) = \sin(2\theta)$ using a trig identity. So we get parametric equations since we have two equation for $x$ and $y$. In some cases, we can make it into a equation with $y$ as a function of $x$. (note in my second big comment, I made a small error: its supposed to be $x = r\cos(\theta)$ and $y = r\sin(\theta)$)

Comment: @PaulthePirate As I stated. Sometimes you can combine the parametric equations and get one equation with both $x$ and $y$ to describe the curve. In your example, using trig identities, we can write $x = \sin(2\theta)$ and $1 - y = \cos(2\theta)$. Thus $x^2 + (1-y)^2 = \sin^2(2\theta) + \cos^2(2\theta) = 1$. So we get the equation $x^2 + (1 - y)^2 = 1$ which is the equation of a circle of radius $1$ centered at the point $(0, 1)$. The polar equation $r = 2\sin(\theta)$ was the exact same graph. Hope this helped. I can't say anything more unless we go into chat.

Answer (score 2):

If

$$x=r\cos t\;,\;y=r\sin t\implies 49=x^2+y^2=r^2\left(\cos^2t+\sin^2t\right)=r^2\implies r=7$$

since always $\,r\ge 0\,$ ...

Comment: You seem to have just restated what I said, I don't understand.

Comment: I can't see why you think that: you wrote that $\,x=7\;,\;y=0\;$ , which makes no sense and, of course, I didn't write... You seemed to be wanting an explanation of why $\,r=7\,$ and this is what I provided.

Comment: Well I know how they got it, but I don't understand why that is true.

Comment: Because of the trigonometric Pythagoras Theorem: $$\cos^2t+\sin^2t=1\implies r^2\cos^2t+r^2\sin^2t=r^2\left(cos^2t+\sin^2t\right)=r^2\cdot 1=r^2$$

Comment: I still don't understand...why does my book give these formulas if they are so hard to use? When can I use them? I can't make sense of this.

Comment: @PaulthePirate and Don: take a step back. Take a deep breath. Stop the bickering. I'm clearing your (rather off-topic) comment exchange above. Paul: you are here for help. You may want to try to not alienate those users who are trying to help you.

Answer (score 1):

This follows from the general conversion formulas from rectangular coordinates to polar coordinates. If $x = r\cos \theta, y = r\sin \theta$, then:

$$x^{2} + y^{2} = (r\cos \theta)^{2} + (r\sin\theta)^{2} = r^{2}(\cos^{2}\theta + \sin^{2}\theta) = r^{2}$$

Hence, if $r = 7$, $x^{2} + y^{2} = r^{2}$ tells us that $x^{2} + y^{2} = 49$.

N.B.: you can verify for yourself that these two equations describe the same geometric object by thinking about what they represent. In polar coordinates, the equation $r = 7$ describes the set of points in the plane that are fixed distance of $7$ from the origin. In the cartesian plane, this describes a circle of radius $7$ centered at the origin, which is described by the equation $x^{2} + y^{2} = 49$.

Comment: What does NB mean?

Comment: @PaulthePirate: it means "nota bene". It means "note well" and is just another way of saying "remark:". :)

Comment: Ok I understand, this seems much easier than the awkward formula the book wants me to memorize./